# Docker MySQL automatical Installation and configuration

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

On old MySQL 5.6 I was automatically installing it and creating all needed users and passwords, using the code below.

Is there a way to do the same on a new MySQL 8.0 so that it automatically installs into docker containers allows root without a password and creates all the above?

```
RUN yum -y install https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch.rpm
RUN yum-config-manager --disable mysql57-community; yum-config-manager --enable mysql56-community
RUN yum -y install mysql-community-server mysql-community-client

#Configure MySQL
# Needed to create system tables etc.
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
su -l mysql -c "/usr/bin/mysql-systemd-start pre"

# Start main service
(su -l mysql -c "/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr") &

# Don't signal startup success before a ping works
su -l mysql -c "/usr/bin/mysql-systemd-start post"

mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`${USERNAME}\`;"
mysql -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \`${USERNAME}\`.* TO \`${USERNAME}\`@'%' IDENTIFIED BY \"${MYSQL_PASS}\";"
mysql -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \`${USERNAME}\`.* TO \`${USERNAME}\`@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY \"${MYSQL_PASS}\";"

mysqladmin shutdown
```

Comment: Have you tried this with MySQL 8.0? Did it fail? How did it fail?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: I tied with MySQL 8, the docker container on systemctl restart gets D-SUB error.

Comment: As a general rule, with docker containers, don't use systemctl. avoid custom images if you can. don't include your database runtime data in your layers. See https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/mariadb-102-centos7/.